Universal property of product
I'm trying to reconcile the commutative diagram for the universal property of the product with my understanding through a concrete example.  I'm very confused by all of this, and would appreciate if someone could tell me whether I have this right or where I'm going wrong.  I'm using the definition of the universal property from Wikipedia, but the diagram below has slightly different symbols than the Wikipedia article.

$\hspace{5cm}$ 

$\mathcal{C}$ the category $\mathbf{Set}$ — the category of sets and functions from sets to sets.  $\mathcal{D}$ the category $\mathbf{Set \times Set}$ — the category of Cartesian products of sets and functions from Cartesian products of sets to Cartesian products of sets.
$X$ an object in $\mathcal{D}$. $A$ and $Y$ objects in $\mathcal{C}$, $g: A \to Y$  a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$.
For example, let $X = \lbrace(0,10), (0,11)\rbrace$ — the Cartesian product $\lbrace 0 \rbrace \times \lbrace 10, 11 \rbrace$, $A = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$,  $Y = \lbrace True \rbrace$, $g: x \to isEven(x)$.
$U: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ the functor between categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$. The functor maps $A$, $Y$ and $g$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to $U(A)$, $U(Y)$ and $U(h)$ in $\mathcal{D}$.
For example, $U(A) = \lbrace (0,10), (0, 11) \rbrace$ — the Cartesian product $A \times \lbrace 10, 11 \rbrace$, $U(Y) = \lbrace (True, True), (True, False) \rbrace$ — the Cartesian product $Y \times \lbrace True, False \rbrace$, $U(g): (x \to isEven(x), y \to isEven(y))$ — a pair of functions, one that takes the first element of $U(A)$ to the first element of $U(Y)$ and one that takes the second element of $U(A)$ to the second element of $U(Y)$.
A universal morphism from $X$ to $U$ is a unique pair $(A, \phi: X \to U(A))$ in $\mathcal{D}$ , which has the following property commonly referred to as the universal property.  For any morphism of the form $f: X \to U(Y)$ in $\mathcal{D}$, there exists a unique morphism $g: A \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, such that the diagram above commutes.
For example, $f: (a,b) \to (isEven(a+10), isEven(b+10))$ — a function that takes a pair and returns a pair.
In this case $\phi$ would be the morphism $\phi: (a,b) \to (\pi_1(a,b), \pi_2(a,b))$ where $\pi_1 : (a,b) \to a$ and $\pi_2: (a,b) \to b$ — a function that takes a pair, projects its first and second components and then wraps it back up into a pair.

I read only the beginning of the text but already noticed a problem. The category $\mathbf{Set}\times\mathbf{Set}$ has as objects ordered pairs of sets, not Cartesian products of sets. And its morphisms are pairs of functions. A morphism from $(A,B)$ to $(X,Y)$ is a pair $(f,g)$ where $f:A\to X$ and $g:B\to Y$.

What's the right way to express the category of Cartesian products of sets?

You don't want a category of cartesian products for this. Did you read the section on the Wikipedia page covering the example of a product?

$\require{AMScd}$First of all, the objects in $\mathsf{Set}\times\mathsf{Set}$ look like $(A,B)$ and not $A\times B$. In general, the category $\mathcal C\times\mathcal C$ is defined as follows:

Objects are ordered pairs of objects in $\mathcal C$, i.e. a typical objects looks like $(A,B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are objects in $\mathcal C$.
Morphisms from $(A,B)$ to $(X,Y)$ are pairs $(f,g)$ where $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon X\to Y$


The way universal property is stated in Wikipedia does not work directly for defining the product, you have to look at the dual of that (reverse all the arrows involved).

Now, the product of two objects is defined as follows: Let $A$ and $B$ be two objects in $\mathcal C$. I will put it in your notation. Let $\mathcal C=\mathsf{Set}$ and $\mathcal{D}=\mathsf{Set}\times\mathsf{Set}$ and let $U$ be the functor sending $A$ to $(A,A)$ and a morphism $f\colon A\to B$ to $(f,f)$. If the product exists, call it $C$, then the universal morphism is the pair $(C,\phi\colon(A,B)\leftarrow U(C))$ (this amounts to two maps $\phi_1\colon C\to A$ and $\phi_2\colon C\to B$, which turn out to be the projection maps) and the universal property is, as said, for any morphism $f\colon (A,B)\leftarrow U(Y)=(Y,Y)$ (again, amounts to two maps $f_1\colon Y\to A$ and $f_2\colon Y\to B$), there exists a unique morphism $g\colon C\leftarrow Y$ such that the following diagram commutes.
$$
\begin{CD}
(A,B) @<\phi<< (C,C) \\
@AfAA @AA(g,g)A \\
(Y,Y) @= (Y,Y)
\end{CD}
$$
Now, this by definition, amounts to the following two diagrams commuting.
$$
\begin{CD}
A @<\phi_1<< C \\
@Af_1AA @AAgA \\
Y @= Y
\end{CD}
$$
$$
\begin{CD}
B @<\phi_2<< C \\
@Af_2AA @AAgA \\
Y @= Y
\end{CD}
$$
Hope this helps. :)

Thanks a lot @Claudius. Is there a way to have these as triangles instead of rectangles? (You can perhaps give me a $\TeX$-$\LaTeX$ SE post link.)

@Claudius, this helps, but now I’m confused about $U(C)$. Isn’t the product $C$ an object in $\mathcal{D}$, and isn’t $U$ a functor from $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ ?

@TomekDobrzynski: Exactly why you should focus on the fact that $\mathcal C\times\mathcal C$ is NOT the category of Cartesian products, but of ordered pairs. The product object is also an object in the same category, for instance, the Cartesian product of two sets is a set, and so is in $\mathsf{Set}$, not in $\mathsf{Set}\times\mathsf{Set}$.

so is $(C,C)$ an order pair of ordered pairs?

@TomekDobrzynski: No. $C$ is an object in $\mathcal C$ and $U(C)=(C,C)$ is just an ordered pair of objects in $\mathcal C$.

so are $A$, $B$, and $C$ all objects in $\mathcal{C}$ and $C$ is the product of $A$ and $B$ ?

@TomekDobrzynski: Yep.

@ultralegend5385, as far as I am aware, there is no way to draw oblique arrows in AMScd. However, this might still be the better solution, as there are several reasons against using pictures.
